# Зачем и почему

Tags: разговорная-речь

Есть ли разница в вопросах: Зачем? и Почему? Если есть,то в каких случаях их употреблять?

Comment: Ну вы используйте это на практике,и вы на собственном опыте поймёте,что это разный вопрос,это совсем другое,ну на улице вечером....,это другое,там ты попался,а так,диффирент...

Comment: Вроде правильно *дифф**е**рент*. В этом контексте — странное использование слова...

Answer (score 5):

«Зачем» спрашивает о цели, а «почему» — о причине.

Часто причина и цель действия совпадают и тогда особых различий нет, но вопрос «*зачем ты такой весёлый?*», в отличие от «*почему...*», смысла не имеет. Обратную картину наблюдаем в вопросах типа «*зачем тебе нож?*»

Answer (score 2):

Для ленивых читайте сразу со слова Итак:

**Зачем** - вопрос по факту произошедшего, о мотивации субъекта действия или обстоятельствах произошедшего. Если о субъекте, то вопрос задается к глаголу прошедшего времени. Если в общем виде или о неодушевлённом чем-то, то может и к глаголу настоящего времени, при этом одушевляя неодушевлённое. Ну и в ряде задач допустимо наличие будущего времени у глагола.

Зачем ты улыбнулся? Зачем льёт дождь(дождь типа получил мотивацию лить)? Зачем Маша пойдет за хлебом в магазин?

При этом вопрос "зачем?" постулирует некий факт, и спрашивает о неизвестных деталях или обстоятельствах которые незнает спрашивающий, которых ему не хватает для составления полной картины происходящего.

А вот употребление "зачем?" с глаголом настоящего времени и субъекте вопросом не является, а является риторической фигурой, понуждением или призывом "не делать так!" Зачем ты стоишь в луже? = Не надо стоять в луже.

Так что фраза "зачем ты такой весёлый?" имеет место быть, но это не вопрос, а мол -  хватит веселиться.

А вопрос **почему** не про незнание деталей, а вопрос сомнения или непонимания. "Почему?" не утверждает никаких фактов, но говорит о представлении или ощущении спрашивающего. Почему идет дождь? - Я не понимаю, представления не имею, почему идет дождь?

Есть заблуждение, что вопрос почему является причинным, это не совсем так, причинным является вопрос "отчего?". То есть его да, применяют в науках в качестве аналога причинного вопроса, но, проблема русского "почему?", в том что он не утверждает обстоятельства или понятия, а задается в лучшем случае об абстрактном основании. Отсюда "почему?" часто могут использовать как аналог вопросов "зачем?", "отчего?", "для чего?". Однако, в таком случае можно получить совсем не тот ответ, который можно ожидать.

Вообще стандартный ответ собеседника на вопрос "почему?" скорее всего будет: я не знаю, ты мне скажи? А если человек таки отвечает на "почему?", то скорее всего ответ не обязательно спрашивающего, и часто побудит задавать новые "почему?"

То есть "почему?" это вопрос вроде: я не понимаю, так как я не уверен в том понимаю ли я правильно обстоятельства, объясни мне чего я не понимаю?

Почему ты такой весёлый? - ты весёлый или мне показалось? мне нужно знать что-то связанно с этим?(а может быть имеется ввиду общий оптимизм человека, тогда) - как быть таким же веселым как и ты? - то есть почему вообще заменяет большинство вопросов, когда человек не в состоянии даже уточнить вопрос. - Верность ответа на "почему?" будет зависеть от того, отгадали ли вы, о чём человек думает, а сказать не может, или нет)

На столе стоит чашка? - далее может следовать - почему на столе, почему чашка, почему стоит, почему на? почему ты спрашиваешь? - а далее может подразумеваться - почему называется чашка? почему ты говоришь чашка? почему ты так уверен? отчего, зачем, для чего, какая чашка, чашка ли это?.. ну и вопрос может задан вообще без уточнения: на столе стоит чашка. - почему?

**Итак**:

Зачем? - про незнание деталей, характера мотивации, дополнительных обстоятельств дела, не хватающих для создания общей картины происходящего. Задается отталкиваясь от утвержденного в вопросе факта.

Почему? - вопрос непонимания любого рода и вида, сомнения, неуверенности в фактичности изложенного в вопросе. Заменяет любые другие вопросы. Успешность ответа на вопрос "почему?" зависит от навыка чтения мыслей или толкования бреда собеседника.

Comment: Зачем так сумбурно писать?

Comment: Конкретнее, где сумбурность. Иначе ваш вопрос смысла не имеет), лучше спросите : почему так сумбурно)? тогда к вам и претензий не будет.

Comment: @Серж короче, считаете сумбурно, помогите исправить.

Comment: @Буратино Прочитал, как и было рекомендовано для ленивых, с Итак. Понравилось, вопросов не возникло.

Comment: Сумбурно — значит путано. Не одна ваша мысль не ясна. Исправить, увы, не могу. Да и зачем? Совет: пишите по существу. Слишком много слов не о чем.

Comment: P.S. Ничего личного.

Comment: @Серж Хотя нет, не так, я бы хотел изменить текст лично под тебя, но пока ты не скажешь, что тебе так, а что не так, я не смогу этого сделать, наверное, или могу? Мне просто любопытно ,смогу ли я выразить для тебя свои мысли по этому поводу понятно?

Comment: Дорогой Буратино! Лично для меня делать ничего не надо. Отвечать надо так, чтобы те задает вопрос или другие пользователи, кто ищет ответ на вопрос, с,могли понять смысл написанного.

Comment: А исправлять чужие тексты у меня нет ни времени, ни сил.

Comment: @Серж Отвечать надо так, чтобы те задает вопрос или другие пользователи - если пользователи не в состоянии сформулировать, что им не понятно, то грош цена такому пониманию. Есть простое правило: критикуешь - предлагай. Только тогда критика имеет смысл и это не просто придирки.

Answer (score 0):

Продолжая ответ предыдущего пользователя, "почему" даёт больше контекста, как и говорилось - он о причине.

Сравните два диалога:

1. — Зачем тебе нож?
   — Защищаться от нападения.
2. — Почему ты носишь с собой нож?
   — Потому что на моего друга в подвортне напали и избили. Я хочу защититься.

Comment: Не надо ничего продолжать. Напишите свой самодостаточный ответ. Никто не будет искать "предыдущего", чтобы понять, о чем вы речь завели.

Comment: Продолжая ваши наблюдения, отмечу: цель действия - это всегда одновременно и причина действия. Но причина действия не всегда цель действия. Я икаю (причина без цели). Я ищу нож чтобы защищаться (цель которую также можно интерпретировать и как причину действия). Я ищу нож потому что хочу защищаться (причина которую также можно интерпретировать и как цель: потому что хочу защищаться= для того чтобы защищаться). То есть вопросы типа "зачем" всегда могут быть заданы без потери смысла через "почему", а обратное не всегда. Это подтверждает и английский Почему = why. А зачем , там нету одним словом.

Comment: Расширьте свой ответ, сделайте его самодостаточным.